# Deferring Attributes To Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have an ActiveRecord Model (I'll refer to as *owner*) that is effectively a container for another type of Model (I'll refer to as *posession*) stored in a `has_many` through association. Effectively almost all of its attributes are based on accumulated data from its many *posessions*.

For example it needs a start and end year which will be based on the earliest and latest years of its *posessions*. It also needs to have a *tags* association that is made up of all the *tags* from all of its *posessions*. So effectively all *owner* is, is an enumeration of the data from all of its *posessions*.

How should I handle this? I need *owners* to be searchable with *pg_search* so I can't simply use virtual attributes as accessors to enumerate the attributes of the *posessions*, and that would be very expensive.

Should I look at having *owner* re-calculate its attributes whenever a *posession* is saved so that they are only recalculated once per change rather than every time they are needed?

I'm at a loss how to handle this so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at using joins?

Comment: @HeliosdeGuerra Please can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using SQL joins?  Something like:

```
@owners = Owner.find(
  :all,
  :select => 'owners.*, sum(possessions.amount) as total_amount',
  :joins => 'left outer join possessions on possessions.owner_id = owners.id',
  :conditions => { 'owners.active => false },
  :group => 'owners.id',
  :order => 'owners.name'
)
```

This gives you an ActiveRecord relation with the extra attributes you define in the select call, so in this instance you could access the sum as an normal attribute, e.g.

```
@owners.first.total_amount
```

Not quite sure how pg_search works, but seems like it'd be compatible w/ a SQL join?

**Edit: Whoops, that initial find should be on Owner, not Possession.**

Comment: Thanks. I guess the problem with this approach is that the attributes are only available on the ActiveRecord instances returned by this query. When `pg_search` or another Gem builds its own query, it won't use a join, so these attributes won't be added.